# Nullable parameter showing incorrect value

Tags: .net, vb.net, parameters, nullable

Can't get my head around this one. I have a method defined like this:

```
Sub M1(searchText As String, companyFilter As Integer?)
    ...
    'Check the value of companyFilter HERE                                          <<<<
    ...
End Sub
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
 M1(txtSearch.Text, If(cbo.SelectedIndex = 0, Nothing, cbo.SelectedValue))
```

`cbo.SelectedIndex` is `0`. What do you expect the value of `companyFilter` to be at the highlighted line? `Nothing`? So do I. But to my surprise the value is `0`. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, VB.NET (like C#) assumes the expression should be of `cbo.SelectedValue`’s type. Try casting it to a `Nullable`:

```
M1(txtSearch.text,
    If(cbo.SelectedIndex = 0, Nothing, New Integer?(cbo.SelectedValue))
```

(… that works, right? Sorry. It’s been a while.) And make sure to have `Option Strict On`.

Comment: A green tick for you. And +1 for reminding me about `Option Strict`. Occasionally I happen to forget it.

Comment: @dotNET: I think you can set the default in the Visual Studio preferences, if you’re using VS! It’s too bad the default defaults aren’t more reasonable.

Comment: Yep. I usually set it from there to have project-wide effect. Just slips out of my mind sometimes, maybe I've got too much attached to C# in recent years.